# iOS: Find a lot of locations with address or zip code

Tags: ios, mapkit, reverse-geocoding

In my app I have a lot of data about a great number of places (e.g. restaurant, museum, etc...) but I haven't coordinate but only address or zip code;
I want to know if address or zip code is possible obtain coordinate for all of my data. I know that I can do it with reverse geocoder but I have a large amount of data; I know that google don't allow make many many request...is there another solution?

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to solve the geocoding problem not using geocoding ?

Comment: No I think that solution can be to have all my result now and after I put them in my app...is there a service where I put my addresses data and it give me all coordinate? Or I do it one at a time?

Comment: I think the geocoding operations are expensive and you'll have to make batch operations with a reasonable delay between them if you want to prepare the offline base for distribution.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple webpage with a javascript that uses Google's API. It would send the address/zip code to Google's geocoder and print the results into a textfield to get their coordinates.